# Java single div open on pageload, collapses when other div header clicked. pop'd with PHP data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

EDITED:  I have created an information display using jquery to show information.  I want to have the top div open one page load.  My current method is to change the name of the top box, and have it act differently.

I am going to use php to populate the divs from a mysql table using a loop, and will not be able to use my current work around.

Is there a smarter way of doing it?

Here is the current script below in action: http://www.luke-sargeant.com/punchline/faq.html.

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $('div.view2').show(); $('div.slide2').click(function() { $(this).next('div.view2').slideToggle('fast'); return false; }); }); </script>

<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $('div.view').hide(); $('div.slide').click(function() { $(this).next('div.view').slideToggle('fast'); return false; }); }); </script>

</div>


<div class="faqlist">
<div class="slide2" style="cursor: pointer;">Where will we meet?</div> 
<div class="view2">In Bristol, we always meet <a href="http://goo.gl/maps/C31Vu" class="bottomlink"> In front In front of the Sainsburys/Subway On Broadquay</a><br /><br />
In Cardiff, the pick up point is at the front of the <a href="http://goo.gl/maps/hwJuq" class="bottomlink">National Museum.</a>

 </div>
<br />
<div class="slide" style="cursor: pointer;">How can I book the trips?</div> 
<div class="view">You can book online using <a href="http://www.paypal.com" class="bottomlink">PAYPAL</a> or speak with the activities coordinator of your school. They can help you to book a trip or <a href="http://www.aftbristol.com/contact.html" class="bottomlink">get in touch</a> </div>
<br />
<div class="slide" style="cursor: pointer;">How do I find out information about trips? </div> 
<div class="view"> Head to the <a href="http://www.aftbristol.com/trip.html" class="bottomlink">trips</a> page click the trip you want, and the information will be available. feel free to <a href="http://www.aftbristol.com/contact.html" class="bottomlink">get in touch</a> if you have any questions. </div>
<br />
<div class="slide" style="cursor: pointer;">What should I bring with me?</div> 
<div class="view">Bring yourself along with the email address you booked the trip with. Be sure to bring a camera and your best smile. Warm clothing for cold days and light clothing for hot ones. Money for food, souvenirs and any extra attractions you may be interested in.</div>
<br />
<div class="slide" style="cursor: pointer;">What happens if I miss a trip? </div> 
<div class="view">you must let us know 24 hours in advance to cancel a daytrip and 7 days before a weekend trip to consider a refund. sometimes we can find someone to take your place, if we can, your money will be refunded to you. If you cannot find the meeting point on the day of departure, or are going to be late contact us. if you provide a mobile telephone number when booking, we will call you if you are late and wait a reasonable time for you to arrive. </div>

     </div><!-- #tab1 -->


 </div> <!-- .tab_container --> 

</div> <!-- #container -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please format and indent your code, it is unreadable. Where exactly do you have an issue? Stack Overflow is not a free feature-coding website.

Comment: Sorry Kyll, That should be better now? also rephrased Q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like Bootstrap JS Collapse better. I tried your code in JSFiddle and it threw errors in the JS portion.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Where will we meet?</h2>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
      <div id="demo" class="collapse in">
        In Bristol, we always meet <a href="http://goo.gl/maps/C31Vu" class="bottomlink"> In front In front of the Sainsburys/Subway On Broadquay</a><br /><br />In Cardiff, the pick up point is at the front of the <a href="http://goo.gl/maps/hwJuq" class="bottomlink">National Museum.</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6dxrake/

Comment: here it is in action.